# MojoExecution Exception in mahout library

Tags: maven, hadoop2, mahout

I am trying to use Mahout Library on top of my Hadoop cluster, I have installed all pre-requisites like Hadoop, java and maven.
I have downloaded Mahout library and when i am trying to use 'mvn install' it is giving me "build failure".

I have tried downloading Mahout from different source, including the latest repo from git, but still getting the same error. I have also re-run the maven with e and X switch, still didn't get anything.[Below is the screenshot of the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZAMK.png)

Thanks for help in advance.

Ali

Comment: Please don't use image and [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55444031/edit) log to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Which `mvn` command are you running?

The error I see looks like you're using a `mvn help` command, which we don't have a target for.

Have you followed the instructions in the README: https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/README.md

Thanks!